# Remove leading zeros from time format

Tags: javascript, regex, time

I am receiving a string in this format `'HH:mm:ss'`. I would like to remove the leading zeros but always keeping the the last four character eg `m:ss` even if `m` would be a zero. I am formatting audio duration.

Examples:

`00:03:15` => `3:15`
`10:10:10` => `10:10:10` 
`00:00:00` => `0:00` 
`04:00:00` => `4:00:00` 
`00:42:32` => `42:32` 
`00:00:18` => `0:18` 
`00:00:08` => `0:08`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this replacement:

```
var result = yourstr.replace(/^(?:00:)?0?/, '');
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/R9IF9Y/2)

or better:

```
var result = yourstr.replace(/^0(?:0:0?)?/, '');
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/R9IF9Y/3)

---

To deal with Matt example (see comments), you can change the pattern to:

```
^[0:]+(?=\d[\d:]{3})
```

Comment: returns `:00:00` for `0:00:00`

Comment: @Matt: from the question: *"I am receiving a string in this format 'HH:mm:ss'"*

Comment: My bad, fair enough

Comment: @Matt: don't worry, you gave me the opportunity to improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked like magic.

Answer (score 9):

If you use 1 h instead of two you will not get the leading 0.

h:mm:ss

Comment: Will it still work for multi digit hours like 10:00

Comment: @NickGallimore yes it does!

Comment: LOL and all that racket above us, hehe (Thanks)

Comment: it does not work for 24 hours.

Comment: @MuhammadAwais it works when you use 24h format h -> H. So 'H:mm:ss' [formatting docs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use moment.js libary.

This supports formats such as

```
var now = moment('1-1-1981 2:44:22').format('h:mm:ss');
alert(now);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8yqxh5mo/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
var tc =['00:03:15', '10:10:10','00:00:00','04:00:00','00:42:32','00:00:18','00:00:08'];

tc.forEach(function(t) {
    var y = t.split(":");
    y[0] = y[0].replace(/^[0]+/g, '');
    if(y[0] === '') {
        y[1] = y[1].replace(/^0/g, ''); 
    }
    var r = y.filter(function(p) {return p!=='';}).join(':');
    console.log(r);
});
```

Divide the time in 3 parts. Remove the leading zeroes from first part, if the the first part is empty remove the leading zeroes from the second part otherwise keep it. Then join all of them discarding the empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with ZUL time when simply format with one small 'h' `moment(date).format('h:mm A')` cuts first digit from time:

and my `const arrivalTime = "2022-07-21T12:10:51Z"`

```
const result = moment(arrivalTime).format(('h:mm A')) // 2:10 PM
```

Solution for that was converting that to ISO format and then format:

```
const arrivalTimeIsoFormat = arrivalTime.toISOString()
const result = moment(arrivalTimeIsoFormat, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS").format(('h:mm A')) // 12:10 PM
```